# Min Entropy per Bit for Trevisan's Extractor/or An Extractor

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness

We know that: trevisan's extractor based on min entropy of the relative system. For trevisan extractor, we need source, seed, min entropy value per bit and error rate for per bit
I have the code for trevisan's extractor and if entropy is small, extractor is working very slow, if entropy is big extractor is working quite fast.

In that case,Does it mean that: to have small min entropy means more randomness and advantage for randomness?

Or randomness is just related to error rate per bits and it is not related to min entropy valu per bits?

And I am using this guideline [Trevisan Extractor](https://easyupload.io/30uop8)

[image]

Comment: Please define Trevisan entropy mathematically so the question is self contained.

Comment: Trevisan is meant to be slow, so that's correct. That's also why it's hardly ever used.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but I wonder that reletionship between randomness and entropy per unit? I mean big entropy of per unit means that, we will have much randomness or randomness is just related to to error rate? or mall entropy means that we are  in more quantum world or not? Thanks for you all answers and helps :)